# Saving Excel workbook to constant path with filename from two fields

Tags: excel, vba, save

I tried to search and put together a code to fit my purpose.

```
Sub save()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAS Filename:="C:\-docs\cmat\Desktop\New folder\ck.xls", FileFormat:= _
  xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
  , CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

How to edit this to:
Instead of naming the saved file ck.xls, generate the filename from the worksheet cells C5 and C8, with a space in the middle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
Sub save()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAS Filename:="C:\-docs\cmat\Desktop\New folder\" & Range("C5").Text & chr(32) & Range("C8").Text &".xls", FileFormat:= _
  xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
 , CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

If you want to save the workbook with the macros use the below code

```
Sub save()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & _
    "\Desktop\" & Range("C5").Text & Chr(32) & Range("C8").Text & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:=vbNullString, WriteResPassword:=vbNullString, _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

if you want to save workbook with no macros and no pop-up use this

```
Sub save()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & _
    "\Desktop\" & Range("C5").Text & Chr(32) & Range("C8").Text & ".xls", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: One more thing about saving file like that. The path you are declaring must exists, otherwise it will not save at all.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, at that time got it done with the help of a friend and the code looks like this.

```
Sub Saving()

Dim part1 As String

Dim part2 As String


part1 = Range("C5").Value

part2 = Range("C8").Value


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _

"C:\-docs\cmat\Desktop\pieteikumi\" & part1 & " " & part2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

How do I edit this part (FileFormat:= _    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled) for it to save as Excel 97-2013 Workbook, have tried several variations with no success.
Thankyou

Seems, that I found the solution, but my idea is flawed. By doing this FileFormat:= _    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, it drops out a popup saying, the you cannot save this workbook as a file without Macro enabled. So, is this impossible?

Comment: I wanted to save it without the macros at all. But it seems, that all is working fine and colleagues have no problems with the files being saved with this extension.