# Changing the default save as location in excel without saving the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which I am creating from another sheet to check whether a calibration is necessary on an instrument. If the calibration is not necessary then the calibration test sheet doesn't need to be saved and ideally should not be.

If the calibration is necessary then I need to save the calibration sheet to a specific folder.

What I want is a script that sets the saveas location so if the user wants to save the file then it will open in the correct location, allowing manual control of saving, perhaps 10 or 20 minutes later (eg triggered by the usual File>save As method). This means I DO NOT want to save within the macro. Sorry if this was not initially clear.

I can't find any function to do this, `Application.DefaultFilePath = savelocation` doesn't work because I am opening an existing template so the default location is always the existing one.

I have run ChDir within my workbook and then gone to file>save as and it changes nothing, it still opens the folder where the current (master) file is saved. `Application.GetSaveAsFileName()` is no use to me because I know where it is saved and where I want to save it, I just don't want to have to navigate there and risk saving to the wrong folder.

Comment: see [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507042/saving-excel-workbook-to-constant-path-with-filename-from-2-fields)

Comment: Have you looked into Application.GetSaveAsFileName() function? The InitialFilename argument should allow you to specify a default path.

Comment: @Siddharth can you please explain why it is not a duplicate?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Sure :) This question is not about saving a file but setting a default path. Read the first 3 lines in my answer. The link given above is about saving a file using saveas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from your query (which also your question title suggest) is that you do not want to save but set a default path. Only if the user wants to save then it should be saved in that directory. If my understanding is correct then you have to set the path using `ChDir()`

For example

```
ChDir "D:\TMP"
```

More from Excel's help

**ChDir Statement**

Changes the current directory or folder.

**Syntax**

ChDir path

The required path argument is a string expression that identifies which directory or folder becomes the new default directory or folder. The path may include the drive. If no drive is specified, ChDir changes the default directory or folder on the current drive.

**Remarks**

The ChDir statement changes the default directory but not the default drive. For example, if the default drive is C, the following statement changes the default directory on drive D, but C remains the default drive:

**EDIT**:

Regarding manual control of saving, you can club `ChDir` with `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` as Dave mentioned in the comments above.

**Followup from Comments**

This is what I tried and it works.

```
Sub Sample()
    ChDir "C:\Temp"

    ret = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Even if I do

```
Sub Sample()
    ChDir "C:\Temp"
End Sub
```

And then manually try to save it using `File-SaveAs`, it opens in the folder that I specified.

**More Followup**

After discussing in chat and working on teamviewer, we realized the problem was the network path so the alternative was to cancel the SaveAs and re-write our own in the class module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ret

    ChDrive "O"
    ChDir "O:\AQS\03 AQS Customers\Calibration Check\Temp"


    If SaveAsUI = True Then
        Cancel = True
        ret = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*")
        '
        '~~> Rest of the code to save the file
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't change anything. Let me try to clarify the last part of the action I need to perform

Comment: I ran the commmand (to a folder that exists) and then before exiting the sub used "file>save As"  and it still opened the existing location of the file

Comment: Like I said the above code is tried and tested. I hope you are not trying to change the drive? See `Remarks`

Comment: I didn't downvote anyone! Your comments are always really helpful.

Sub test()
ChDrive "C"
ChDir "C:\Maconomy"
End Sub

I step through this and then click save as in an *existing opened workbook*. Could it being opened be responsible?

Comment: Oh I thought you did :D

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to leave comments as to why you felt this question deserved downvoting?

Comment: Chat deleted as it contained some extra information which is confidential and may not be relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sub SaveWorkbookToDifferentDirectoryWithoutChangingFilename()

ChDrive "Y"

ChDir "Y:\Existing File Name"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

End Sub
```